# Distortion during window-resizing, typing in the address bar of firefox and in other places

Tags: screen, window, resize

I'm facing a screen distortion problem, when I'm trying to resize a window. It can be a window of any application, like file manager, VLC, Firefox, anything.

The distortions happen in flashes, like blinking- distortion and then normal again, then again...

The distortion isn't permanent, the window becomes completely normal when I'm done...

It doesn't happen all the time, but it happens and that's what's been bothering me...

Below is a screen-shot of what happens:

[Window distortion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPgkE.jpg)

Also, I've noticed that when I'm typing something in the address bar of Firefox to Google something, the suggestions/suggestion bars also blinks with similar distortions...

I'm also noticing these type of problems when I'm going fullscreen on VLC, and then back in normal window mode...

It seems whenever there's movement, the problem occurs...

I'm editing this post to add more issues, and I still haven't gotten any solution here yet...

I know it might be nothing, but it's still something; I mean this shouldn't happen right?!

I'm sorry, in advance, if my question is too trivial or minor to even consider as a user...

Below is my output by `inxi -Fx`

```
    System:    Host: apollonius Kernel: 4.10.0-28-generic x86_64
           bits: 64 gcc: 5.4.0
           Desktop: Unity 7.4.0 (Gtk 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3)
           Distro: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Machine:   Device: desktop System: ASUS product: All Series serial: N/A
           Mobo: ASUSTeK model: H81M-C v: Rev X.0x serial: N/A
           BIOS: American Megatrends v: 3501 date: 10/21/2016
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i5-4460 (-MCP-) 
           arch: Haswell rev.3 cache: 6144 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 25540
           clock speeds: max: 3400 MHz 1: 3200 MHz 2: 3200 MHz 3: 3200 MHz
           4: 3200 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
           bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.3 )
           drivers: modesetting (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1360x768@60.02hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Haswell Desktop
           version: 4.5 Mesa 17.0.7 Direct Render: Yes
Audio:     Card Intel 8 Series/C220 Series High Def. Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.10.0-28-generic
Network:   Card: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCIE Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: e000 bus-ID: 03:00.0
           IF: enp3s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full
           mac: f8:32:e4:9d:66:b6
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 507.9GB (22.6% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: TOSHIBA_DT01ACA0 size: 500.1GB
           ID-2: USB /dev/sdb model: USB_Flash_Drive size: 7.8GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 113G used: 5.6G (6%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda3
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 8.00GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda4
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 29.8C mobo: 27.8C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: 0
Info:      Processes: 220 Uptime: 2:56 Memory: 1631.4/7852.7MB
           Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 5.4.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.3.481) inxi: 2.3.39
```

Some more information that might be helpful in solving this problem...

[lshw output](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/25580630/)

[glxinfo output](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/25580643/)

[Another output](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/25580724/)

Comment: From what you've posted I assume the issue is  due to absence of vsync, is there issue with video playback too ?, i.e when frames in video change you can notice some tearing effect.

Comment: I don't think so... I haven't noticed any tearing effect on my videos( I think!)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue may not be related to the kernel, because it might be solved using some other methods, but changing/downgrading my kernel from `4.10.0-28` to `4.4.0-28` seems to have solved the distortion issues...

I have also used kernel `4.4.0-89` and that also seems to work fine. I tested using these kernels only because I used to use them on Linux Mint, so I trusted them to see if they can get me out of this problem...

From a similar point of view, I upgraded my kernel from the default `4.10.0-28` to `4.10.0-31`(the update was available in the Software Updater utility) to see if that solves it, but it didn't...

So far, I haven't faced any distortion issues on these 4.4.0-x kernel series, neither in Firefox, nor in resizing application windows and other cases...