# Kernel installation by using Synaptic

Tags: kernel, synaptic, downgrade

As part of my investigation of the [distortion issues](https://askubuntu.com/q/957241/736807) I'm having, I was going to try installing an older kernel that I used to use when I was on Mint...

I found a article here that explains removal of kernels by means of Synaptic, so I was thinking of installing using that...

So there are a total of three things to install right?

1. linux-headers-4.4.0-28 (4.4.0-28.47)
2. linux-headers-4.4.0-28-generic (4.4.0-28.47)
3. linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic (4.4.0-28.47)

I installed these three packages, updated my grub and tried booting in that kernel, but some things went was wrong...

1. Ubuntu logo with the name itself disappeared after a while, with only the "loading dots" remaining...
2. Weird animations started to occur; the login screen came at last after successive page-flip animations...
3. Keyboard and mouse weren't working...

So what went wrong? Am I supposed to install other packages along with those three? In case of kernel update through Synaptic, [Ubuntu community help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Upgrade) just mentioned of installing the linux-image package, so that's what I did matching with my current kernel and what else related is installed...

Comment: you might need linux-image-extras.  for your video driver

Comment: @ravery Synaptic also has a option called "Mark suggested for installation", do I need to install those as well(those suggested packages aren't installed for the current kernels on my system, so I guess it's a no...)?

Comment: the suggested are probably the packages for  building kernel modules

Comment: probably nothing went wrong, but that kernel isn't compatible with your hardware... In any case, it's not very clear what your actual question is here. What's your goal now? What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: @Zanna As ravery suggested, installing the linux-image-extras solved the problem...